# d.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am using Drawer in a Fragment Floating Button whose value is getting null.

When clicking on Drawer item it is getting closed.  Can anybody explain why?

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.mubeen.emei;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Category_Item extends Fragment {

    FloatingActionButton fab;
    public Category_Item() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SaveCategory fragment = new SaveCategory();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1_container, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getActivity().setTitle(R.string.Save_Category);
               return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category__item, container, false);    
    }
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
12-26 05:22:50.952 9530-9530/com.example.mubeen.emei W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
12-26 05:22:53.902 9530-9530/com.example.mubeen.emei D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-26 05:22:53.902 9530-9530/com.example.mubeen.emei E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mubeen.emei, PID: 9530
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
on a null object reference
at com.example.mubeen.emei.Category_Item.button(Category_Item.java:49)
at com.example.mubeen.emei.Category_Item.onCreateView(Category_Item.java:37)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:106)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:124)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Clean your post please. Read FAQ or visit the most popular posts to get to know how questuion should look like

Answer (score 0):

initialize your FloatingActionButton fab in your code ..

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreateView` method use this.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              //Enter your code here to do something after clicking Floating Actionbar
        }
    });
```

I think this may help you.